# Recover storage spaces pool

Tags: data-recovery, storage-spaces

I've got an old 5x5TB storage pool that I am convinced I set up with two-way parity at the time but now it seems is actually just one-way parity that right now refuses to function anymore. One disk failed as I was preparing to backup all the data, and another now refuses to attach.

```
PS> get-storagepool -isprimordial 0 | get-physicaldisk

Number FriendlyName SerialNumber MediaType CanPool OperationalStatus  HealthStatus Usage          Size
------ ------------ ------------ --------- ------- -----------------  ------------ -----          ----
7      052135       00A1234567F6 HDD       False   OK                 Healthy      Auto-Select 4.55 TB
3      182565       00A123456882 HDD       False   OK                 Healthy      Auto-Select 4.55 TB
6      069705       00A1234567F6 HDD       False   OK                 Healthy      Auto-Select 4.55 TB
       127838       95RDK98JF57D HDD       False   Lost Communication Warning      Auto-Select 4.55 TB
       184587       95N2Y1D0F57D HDD       False   Lost Communication Warning      Retired     4.55 TB
```

the one that's marked as retired is dead and will not work, the other one should still function but for some reason refuses. If that drive is plugged in by itself the storage space is not detected and it's listed as `storage spaces protective partition` in Disk Management.

Would anyone know how to reattach that one drive, or some other trick to recover some more data from the pool?

it currently shows up as:

```
PS> get-virtualdisk

ResiliencySettingName FaultDomainRedundancy OperationalStatus                     HealthStatus  Size FootprintOnPool StorageEfficiency
--------------------- --------------------- -----------------                     ------------  ---- --------------- -----------------
Parity                1                     {No Redundancy, Degraded, Incomplete} Unhealthy    15 TB         22.1 TB            64.71%
```

---

Edit: don't assume there is a backup, there is no backup. The backup was supposed to be the 2-disk failover. The theoretical backup does also not answer the question. It's non critical data, while it's not great if it's gone, it won't hurt that much, I'm just trying to recover as much as possible.

---

I've tried running ReclaiMe Storage Spaces Recovery, which seems to work, however it is not worth a $300 licence to me to try and recover the files.

Comment: fastest way: use the backup from the day before.

Answer (score 3):

Devastate your Storage Spaces pool and create new one from scratch. Get data back from backup.

Edit: Sorry to hear there’s no backup. See, RAID is no backup. In your case you may try to eject all the disks, mount them into some other machine and “import” Storage Spaces pool. Storage Spaces is fragile and unreliable tech, so in some cases these “unplug-n-plug-back” helps.